# Start Tkinter in background

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Comically enough, I was really annoyed when tkinter windows opened in the background on Mac. However, now I am on Linux, and I want tkinter to open in background.

I don't know how to do this, and when I google how to do it, all I can find are a lot of angry Mac users who can't get tkinter to open in the foreground.

I should note that I am using python2.7 and thus Tkinter not tkinter (very confusing).

Comment: Does `root.lower()` work for you? For me on Win7 it works, but im not sure about linux.

Comment: `lower` ought to move the window behind all other open windows. I believe it will still steal focus away from the current active window, however. I don't know if you can do anything about that.

Comment: root.lower() doesn't even move the window to the background on LinuxMint. ?

Comment: Ah! Yes it does. I just had to call it after `root.attributes("-zoomed", True)` and `root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)`. Thanks!

Comment: It may be a good idea to actually answer your own question if you found the resolution. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Linux Mint. In order to make a program not show up in the foreground (i.e. be hidden behind all of the other windows), one should use `root.lower()` as aforementioned in the comments. However, please note (and this seems to happen on multiple platforms) that `root.lower()` will **not** change the focus of the window. Therefore, even if you use `.lower()` and run the script, and if you press [alt] + [F4], for example, the Tkinter window that was just opened (even though you cannot see it) will be closed.

I noticed, however, that it is prudent to place the `root.lower()` after attributes for the Tkinter root. For example, if you use `root.attributes("-zoomed", True)` to expand the window, be sure to place `root.lower()` after the `root.attributes(..)`. Moreover, it did not work for me when I put `root.lower()` before `root.attributes(..)`.